# Moving a div using mouse which is inside another div?

Tags: javascript

I have a div, inside that i have dynamically created another div.I need to move the dynamically created div and have to place it in desired position..Please Help.

I am having one main div. i am creating multiple divs dynamically using javascript and appending with main div as it's child.I have to move the dynamically created divs inside the main div on dragging on each div.I am able to get id of currently selected div(created dynamically)

Comment: How you mean 'using mouse' ??? c'mon there's a dozens of ways to do it with the mouse: dragging... clicking on a desired place... follow mouse-position... You really have to be more specific asking questions and showing some initial effort.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out jqueryUI's [draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable)?

After you have have loaded jquery and jquery ui on your page, you can make any dom element draggable with a code like this

```
$('div.inside').draggable();
```

If you want to constraint the draggable movement you can pass the wrapper into containment option, like this

```
$('div.inside').draggable({containment : 'div.outer'});
```

Or specifically if you want to contain it to the parent div just pass parent in the option, like this:

```
$('div.inside').draggable({containment : 'parent'});
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/juzerali/ehVKt/)

Comment: I am having one main div. i am creating multiple divs dynamically using javascript and appending with main div as it's child.I have to  move the dynamically created divs inside the main div on dragging on each div.I am able to get id of currently selected div(created dynamically)

Comment: If you have the id then you can make it draggable like this:
`$('#idOfDynamicallyCreatedDiv').draggable({containment : 'parent'});`

Comment: Don't forget to include jquery, jqueryui and jquerycss file in your page before this code.

Comment: can i get a solution using java script alone

Comment: Lots of coding and cross browser issues that will have to be taken care of. Try searching in [w3schools](w3schools.com) I am sure you will find what you are looking for.